# Saving text within a UITextView with NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios6, uitextview, xcode4.5, nsuserdefaults

Is there a way to save the text within a UITextView using NSUserDefaults? When I use it for a UITextField it works just fine. Here is the code I use for a UITextField:

-(void)viewDidLoad {

```
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSString *text1 = [defaults objectForKey:@"text1"];
 textfield1.text = text1;
```

}

-(IBAction)saveButton {

```
 [textfield1 resignFirstResponder];
 NSString *text1 = [textfield1 text];
 NSUserDefaults *myDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [myDefaults setObject:text1 forKey:@"text1"];
 [myDefaults synchronize];
 NSLog(@"Data Saved")
```

}

However, if I use this simple way to save for a UITextView instead of a UITextField the data within the view doesn't save. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact same code you used for UITextField should work for UITextView; the method `text` works for both.

This code worked for me:

```
[textView resignFirstResponder] ;
NSString* textViewContents = textView.text ;
NSLog(@"textViewContents is: %@", textViewContents) ;

NSUserDefaults* userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] ;
[userDefaults setObject:textViewContents forKey:@"textView"] ;
[userDefaults synchronize] ;
```

I'd guess that your problem lies in accessing your UITextView's text. NSLog it, as I did above, and see if it's as you expected.